# Leaflet nestinf IF condition inside the onEachFeature function

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I would like to set up my pop-up content based at conditional statement.
I've got two approaches behind myself, none of them was working so far.

The first one:

```
 onEachFeature: function (pointFeature, layer) {
 function Stream() {
  if (pointFeature.properties.Stream = 1) {
    "<p> Live Stream </p>"
  } else { "<p> Image refresh </p>"}
  }
  var popupContent = "<p><h2 class='webcam_location'>" +
    pointFeature.properties.Location + "</h2></p>" + 
    "<h4 class='webcam_provider'>" + pointFeature.properties.Provider + "</h4>" +
    "<iframe src='" + pointFeature.properties.Link + "' height='200' width='300' title='camera 
    thumbnail'></iframe>" +
      Stream()
      };
     layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
    }
```

The second one:

```
  onEachFeature: function (pointFeature, layer) {
   var popupContent = "<p><h2 class='webcam_location'>" +
    pointFeature.properties.Location + "</h2></p>" + 
    "<h4 class='webcam_provider'>" + pointFeature.properties.Provider + "</h4>" +
    "<iframe src='" + pointFeature.properties.Link + "' height='200' width='300' title='camera 
    thumbnail'></iframe>" +
      if (pointFeature.properties.Stream = 1) {
        "<p> Live Stream </p>"
      } else { "<p> Image refresh </p>"}
      };
    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
```

with an error in the console:

**SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'if'**

How can I place if statement inside the existing function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the concatenation with [template literal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and use a separate concatenation for your conditional text.

Like so:

UPDATE: Based upon your comments, I've amended the solution to more closely match your provided fiddle.

This should be close enough for you to adapt.

First, save the popup content and the conditional content to  variables. Build the string with the variables needed, including the conditional content. Then use that single variable (`popUpContent`) as the content to add to the popup.

```js
onEachFeature: function(pointFeature, layer) {
  const stream = pointFeature.properties.Stream;
  let popUpConditionalContent;

  if (stream === 1) {
    popUpConditionalContent = "<p class='webcam_refresh'> Live Stream </p>"
  } else {
    popUpConditionalContent = "<p class='webcam_refresh'> Image refresh </p>"
  }

  const popUpContent = `<p><h2 class='webcam_location'>
    ${pointFeature.properties.Location}</h2></p>
    <h4 class='webcam_provider'>${pointFeature.properties.Provider}</h4>
    <iframe src='${pointFeature.properties.Link}' height='200' width='300' title='camera 
  thumbnail '></iframe>${popUpConditionalContent}<b class='popup_category'>Rotation:</b>${pointFeature.properties.Rotation}${stream}`;

  var popUp = L.popup({
    className: 'map-popup',
  }).setContent(popUpContent);

  layer.bindPopup(popUp);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to place this separate concatenation in the middle of my popupContent?

Comment: Why is that important to you? Why does this result not work or seem wrong?

Comment: Do you mean you want that "Live Stream" or "Image Refresh" text between the `<h4>` and the `<iframe>`?

Comment: Let me know what you want and I'll fix it up for you.

Comment: The code is here (without library). I tried to nest a variable inside the other variable.
https://jsfiddle.net/06hgnx2q/
but I get just the GeoJSON value instead of the string.

Comment: there you go, updated the answer to reflect your fiddle.

Comment: Yes! It's fantastic! Thank you! Since now I will know how to define if statements inside the functions like this.

Comment: Glad to help. Have fun!